# python dataframe how to delete some rows based on index conditions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

To say I had a daily price dataframe with the date as its index. and I'd like to delete all the rows if its index date <"2010/1/1" . I tried `bars.drop(bars.index<'2010/7/17'== True)` It raised an error `ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()` . Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: Could you show your dataframe?

Comment: doesn't `bars.loc[bars.index >= '2010/1/1']` work?

Comment: @EdChum Yeah. It works. Thx.

Comment: Sorry try `bars[bars.index >= '2010/1/1']`

Comment: What about `bars.drop(bars.index[bars.index<'2010/7/17'])`?

Answer (score 0):

If you actually wants to `drop` rows with your condition you could do following:

```
bars.drop(bars.index[bars.index<'2010/1/1'])
```

But it's better to slice dataframe using @EdChum solution with `loc`.